# Add a footerview to a Tab host Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-tabhost, footer

I would like to add a footer view, a counter of the elements loaded in a list view. I would like to know where sholuld i put the footer view. I've already one in my listview and i suppose that i must not put it there because i want it vissible all the time, not when i get to the bottom of it like the one i have.

Code:

ListView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lista"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stackFromBottom="false"
    android:transcriptMode="normal"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code of the tabs:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainTabActivity" >
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_vertical|fill_horizontal" >
        </TabWidget>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >                   
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lista"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:stackFromBottom="false"
                    android:transcriptMode="normal"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="b"
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="c"
            </LinearLayout>                
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="d"
            </LinearLayout>                            
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>                      
</TabHost>
```

I have this: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/23/6a3t.jpg/

And i would like this: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/809/kesm.jpg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the FrameLayout with match_parent width and height inside a LinearLayout all the content will hide out of the screen.

There are 2 forms to add that footer:

First, set the framelayout with this sizes:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
```

Two, use a RelativeLayout and set all content bellow others and add the footer with layout_alignParentBottom = true if you want to add the footer above the content or bellow the last view if you want that the footer be with the content.

Answer (score 0):

How about [`ListView.addFooterView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29)?

From documentation:

> Add a fixed view to appear at the bottom of the list. If addFooterView
>   is called more than once, the views will appear in the order they were
>   added. Views added using this call can take focus if they want.
>
> NOTE: Call this before calling setAdapter. This is so ListView can
>   wrap the supplied cursor with one that will also account for header
>   and footer views.

Comment: I've already setted a footerview to the list view, besides, that solution wont work for what i need

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you.

create a file called `footer.xml`
and add this code to it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom"
 android:layout_weight=".15"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/bckkaup" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lborder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".14"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_left_button"
        android:src="@drawable/over_9"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/unknown"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".14"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_left_button"
        android:src="@drawable/cartoon_9"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/open"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".14"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_left_button"
        android:src="@drawable/gallery_9"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"

        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.03" 
        android:src="@drawable/action_bar_right_button"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_left_button"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/opencam"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".14"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_left_button"
        android:src="@drawable/camera_9"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".14"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_left_button"
        android:src="@drawable/stylish_9"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rborder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_left_button"
        android:src="@drawable/frame_9"
        android:layout_weight=".14" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

and then in your `main layout`
add this code

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/down"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <include
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/footer" >

    </include>
</LinearLayout>
```

this will give you a footer. and you can change the gravity to make it as header as well. 
i know you are asking for tabs, but thought i should share it with you maybe it benefit you in anyway.